# What's wrong with my regex for validating password?

Tags: php, regex

Here is my pattern for validating password:

```
$pattern = '/^[0-9A-Za-z!@#$^%*_|;:\'"`~.,\(\)\{\}\[\]\<\>\\\/\?\-\+\=\&]{6,}$/m';
```

I use function `preg_match` to validate

```
preg_match($pattern, $string);
```

But when I run it, it shows this error:
`Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '\' in xxx on line 13`

What's wrong with my regex?

Here is the regular expression explained: http://regex101.com/r/rR6uH0/

```
^ assert position at start of a line
[0-9A-Za-z!@#$^%*_|;:'"`~.,\(\)\{\}\[\]\<\>\\\/\?\-\+\=\&]{6,} match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: Between 6 and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
!@#$^%*_|;:'"`~., a single character in the list !@#$^%*_|;:'"`~., literally
\( matches the character ( literally
\) matches the character ) literally
\{ matches the character { literally
\} matches the character } literally
\[ matches the character [ literally
\] matches the character ] literally
\< matches the character < literally
\> matches the character > literally
\\ matches the character \ literally
\/ matches the character / literally
\? matches the character ? literally
\- matches the character - literally
\+ matches the character + literally
\= matches the character = literally
\& matches the character & literally
$ assert position at end of a line
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to "validate"? The simple, straightforward regex for six or more non-space ASCII printable characters is `[!-~]{6,}` but why would you disallow spaces from passwords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the forward slashes twice. The reason why you sometimes need to escape double slashes is that they are stripped twice -- once by PHP engine (at compile time) and once by regular expression engine.

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php):

> Single and double quoted PHP strings have special meaning of backslash. Thus if \ has to be matched with a regular expression \, then "\\" or '\\' must be used in PHP code.

The updated regular expression should look like:

```
$pattern = '/^[0-9A-Za-z!@#$^%*_|;:\'"`~.,\(\)\{\}\[\]\<\>\\\\\/\?\-\+\=\&]{6,}$/m';
```

Comment: Yeah, I have read the same link of yours. And I'm agree with you with your solution.